# Scrape Dynamic contents created by Javascript using Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrap DIV content created by javascript function by using python script. I have tried with BS4 and by doing with that i'm not able to get dynamic data. instead it shows only the source code.

Sample code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://rawgit.com/skysoft999/tableauJS/master/example.html"
r = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')


for row in soup.findAll('div', attrs = {'class':'quote'}):
    print(row)


print(soup.prettify())
```

Sample HTML source code is in [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/hjnXwddz)

Sample data to be extracted:

[image]

Comment: BeautifulSoup can not parse the content created with JS, you need to use `selenium` maybe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The initial HTML does not contain the data you want to scrape, that's why using only `BeautifulSoup` is not enough. You can load the page with [`Selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and then scrape the content.

**Code:**

```
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

html = None
url = 'http://demo-tableau.bitballoon.com/'
selector = '#dataTarget > div'
delay = 10  # seconds

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

try:
    # wait for button to be enabled
    WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'getData'))
    )
    button = browser.find_element_by_id('getData')
    button.click()

    # wait for data to be loaded
    WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector))
    )
except TimeoutException:
    print('Loading took too much time!')
else:
    html = browser.page_source
finally:
    browser.quit()

if html:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    raw_data = soup.select_one(selector).text
    data = json.loads(raw_data)

    import pprint
    pprint.pprint(data)
```

**Output:**

```
[[{'formattedValue': 'Atlantic', 'value': 'Atlantic'},
  {'formattedValue': '6/26/2010 3:00:00 AM', 'value': '2010-06-26 03:00:00'},
  {'formattedValue': 'ALEX', 'value': 'ALEX'},
  {'formattedValue': '16.70000', 'value': '16.7'},
  {'formattedValue': '-84.40000', 'value': '-84.4'},
  {'formattedValue': '30', 'value': '30'}],
  ...
]
```

The code assumes that the button is initially disabled: `<button id="getData" onclick="getUnderlyingData()" disabled>Get Data</button>` and data is not loaded automatically, but due to the button being clicked. Therefore you need to delete this line: `setTimeout(function(){ getUnderlyingData(); }, 3000);`.

You can find a working demo of your example here: http://demo-tableau.bitballoon.com/.

Comment: One of the most helpful answer that i ever received. You saved my day. I appreciate your quick response and skill.

Comment: @Jatimir how can I scrape the same problem as mentioned in the question, but the element is generated by a PHP script. Here is my question. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60592818/how-to-scrape-a-span-which-is-produced-by-a-script-each-5-minutes-inside-a-div)

Comment: any way to use this to scrape this site?
https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/INDEX-MMTW/